NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' in Unity 2D
I'm getting a nullreference exception for this line:
maxHealthRemainder = playerHealth.maxHealth % 2;
here's my code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthBarUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject heartPrefab;
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    List<HealthHeart> hearts = new List<HealthHeart>();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PlayerHealth.OnPLayerDamaged += DrawHearts;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerHealth.OnPLayerDamaged -= DrawHearts;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        DrawHearts();
    }

    public void CreateEmptyHeart()
    {
        GameObject newHeart = Instantiate(heartPrefab);
        newHeart.transform.SetParent(transform);
        HealthHeart heartComponent = newHeart.GetComponent<HealthHeart>();
        heartComponent.SetHeartImage(HeartStatus.Empty);
        hearts.Add(heartComponent);
    }

    public void DrawHearts()
    {
        ClearHearts();
        int maxHealthRemainder = 0;
        maxHealthRemainder = playerHealth.maxHealth % 2;
        int heartsToMake = (int)(playerHealth.maxHealth / 2 + maxHealthRemainder);
        for(int i=0; i<heartsToMake ; i++)
        {
            CreateEmptyHeart();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<hearts.Count; i++)
        {
            int heartStatusRemainder = (int)Mathf.Clamp(playerHealth.currentHealth - (i*2), 0, 2);
            hearts[i].SetHeartImage((HeartStatus)heartStatusRemainder);
        }
    }
    public void ClearHearts()
    {
        foreach(Transform T in transform )
        {
            Destroy(T.gameObject);
        }
        hearts = new List<HealthHeart>();
    }
}



playerHealth is probably null.  If it's a property that needs to be hooked up in the UI, make sure you do that.

well, then apparently playerHealth is null then

I gave playerHealth all of the values needed when I hooked it up in the UI

Nowhere in that code is playerHealth initialized.  You create it ( public PlayerHealth playerHealth;) but do not initialize it. Its likely a different object than the one you "hooked up"
